# how to change this regex so it selects paragraphs elements with more than one img

Tags: php, html, css, regex, wordpress

This is a follow-up question to: [Differentiating between P tags wrapping images and P tags wrapping text nodes in Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1733175/differentiating-between-p-tags-wrapping-images-and-p-tags-wrapping-text-nodes-in)

I would like to modify the solution:

```
 function my_content_filter($content) {
   return preg_replace('|<p>(<img[^<]*)</p>|i', '<p class="foo">${1}</p>', $content);
 }
 add_filter('the_content', 'my_content_filter');`
```

So that it works for a `<p>` with more than one `<img>` element.

Comment: This might be more easily accomplished using the DOM tree, if you can get to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try if this works for you.

```php
function my_content_filter($content) {
return preg_replace('|<p>((<img[^>]*>)*)<\/p>|i', '<p class="foo">${1}</p>', $content);
}
add_filter('the_content', 'my_content_filter');`
```